# Dealing with missing metrices in calculations

Tags: prometheus, promql

I use a formula to calculate *approx.* maximum memory consumption of *MySQL* instances that (simplified and written in *PromQL*) reads:

```
(
    mysql_global_variables_key_buffer_size +
    mysql_global_variables_query_cache_size +
    mysql_global_variables_tmp_table_size +
    mysql_global_variables_innodb_buffer_pool_size +
    mysql_global_variables_innodb_additional_mem_pool_size +
    mysql_global_variables_innodb_log_buffer_size +
    (
        mysql_global_variables_max_connections *
        (
            mysql_global_variables_sort_buffer_size +
            mysql_global_variables_read_buffer_size +
            mysql_global_variables_read_rnd_buffer_size +
            mysql_global_variables_join_buffer_size +
            mysql_global_variables_thread_stack +
            mysql_global_variables_binlog_cache_size
        )
    )
)
```

Unfortunately the `mysql_global_variables_innodb_additional_mem_pool_size` metric is not always present for every instance resulting in "no data" if this it is included in the calculation.

There's the [`absent(v instant-vector)`](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/functions/#absent) function that *may* be used to solve this but I am not sure how.

I would like *nonexistent* metrices be replaced with a constant (`0` in this case). Is it possible?

Could you please provide me with some hints on how to deal with missing metrices in calculations in *PromQL*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
mysql_global_variables_innodb_additional_mem_pool_size or up * 0
```

https://www.robustperception.io/existential-issues-with-metrics/ looks at this problem in more detail.

Comment: That's *nifty trick* (and great blog post)! Thanks, Brian. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted solution won't work well in case we would try to sum two metrics both of them can be missing.
In my specific case it is `mysql_info_schema_innodb_metrics_transaction_trx_rseg_history_len` (from mariadb) and `mysql_global_status_innodb_history_list_length` (from mysql).
Provided solution gave me 3 graphs for a single host.

I used the following workaround:

```
(metric1{hostname="h"} or on() vector(0))+(metric2{hostname="h"} or on() vector(0))
```

taken from here: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/2393#issuecomment-192522042